# Python regex: re.sub() not handling correctly accented chars, in opposition to re.compile().sub()

Tags: python, regex, python-unicode

I need to strip a string from non-word chars:

```
>>>string = u'_Óscar;'
>>>print re.sub(r'[_\W]*', u'', string, re.UNICODE)
scar
```

...but re.sub() confuses accented letters as non-word chars (\W). This is: by mistake, re.sub() removes 'Ó' from 'Óscar'.

However, re.compile().sub() handles correctly the accented letter:

```
>>>string = u'_Óscar;'
>>>print re.compile('[_\W]*', re.UNICODE ).sub(u'', string)
Óscar
```

re.compile().sub() removes the underscore and the semicolon, but leaves correctly the 'Ó' in place.

Is there any regex-algorithmic difference between re.sub() and re.compile().sub()?
I guess I am missing something.

---

EDIT: solved thanks to @JonClements comment: I was wrongly setting the re.UNICODE flag. It should be set: `flags=re.UNICODE`.
So the following works just fine:

```
re.sub(r'[_\W]*', u'', string, flags=re.UNICODE)
re.compile('[_\W]*', flag=re.UNICODE ).sub(u'', string)
```

Comment: The first looks like it should be `flags=re.UNICODE` otherwise, the argument `re.UNICODE` is being used as the number of times to perform a replacement and no flags are being passed - meaning the `re.UNICODE` flag is never being set

Comment: @JonClements:  `re.sub(r'\W', '', p, flags=re.UNICODE)` solved it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @COLDSPEED: Shall I say that this question doesn't seem to me a duplicate of this other one: [regex.sub() gives different results to re.sub()][1] albeit its title:

- In this second question, the code sets the `re.L` flag; instead of `re.UNICODE`, the flag I was trying to use.

- And in my code, the error comes from wrongly feeding the flag to the methods (missing the 'flag=' part); whilst in the other question the error comes from not feeding the same flag to both methods.
  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602177/regex-sub-gives-different-results-to-re-sub